# Get the data from a measure filter via API in sonarqube

Tags: api, filter, sonarqube, measure

Does anyone know how I can get via the API of sonarqube the data from a self created measure filter.

I can retrieve with excel the data from project xy but I want to have the aggregation from measure filter.
Is there any option to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this isn't available yet, but it's there in SonarQube backlog: [SONAR-5309](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONAR-5309) (you can vote/watch for it in Jira).

Until then you'll have to query all measures using [api/measures](https://nemo.sonarqube.org/web_api/api/measures) and do the filtering on client side.